# How likely is it that AES-256 is crackable within 100 years (2120)?

Tags: aes, grovers-algorithm

When people ask for a block-cipher with a larger key space than AES-256 replies usually just state that there is no need. I see where that is coming from the future is hard to predict.

The two main problems I can see are Grover's algorithm (see below) and the fact that we can not see all the problems.

I have no idea how powerful quantum computers will be in 2120 so we may consider upper bounds. e.g. At 20ºC, the Landauer limit* is about 2^-80 watt-hours per bit. I do know that some other ciphers (like threefish) have larger key spaces.

The fact that AES may be broken within 100 years (exactly) was apparently addressed by the [OneHundredYearCryptography project](https://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs/wiki/OneHundredYearCryptography) by XORing it with XSalsa20.

To reiterate I want to know if AES-256 will be safe throughout our life time.

*To the best of my knowledge, experimental quantum computers that operate at the limit are actually much faster than other experimental computers that are also at/near the limit. I don't know if there is a price difference however.

Edit for background: Grover's algorithm is an attack that is analogous to brute force attack. The differences are that its complexity is the square root of the key space (2^(256/2)) rather than the key space itself, and that it can only be run on a quantum computer. I'm confident that no conventional or quantum computer will be able near-brute-force it, but I'm not that sure that a quantum computer won't be able to Grover it. Therefore, the power of quantum computers by 2120 is of more interest than the power of electrical computers at that time.

Comment: AES-256 implementations are cracked thru side channels (timing/cache, DPA/DEMA). I find it credible that this will remain the main and the only exploited security issue of AES, with the marginally satisfactory block width a distant second concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know if AES-256 will be safe throughout our life time.

No one knows that.  Here is what we do know:

- A brute force search (by conventional computers) will be totally impossible.  This can be shown by a power analysis of the minimal amount of power used per step (the minimal amount of power to change a state is $kT$, where $k$ is Boltzman's constant circa $1.38 \cdot 10^{-16} \text{ erg/}^\circ\text{K}$, and $T$ is the temperature in Kelvin.  If we assume a computer that's running at cosmic background radiation temperature ($3.2 ^\circ K$), the minimal energy to step a counter though $2^{256}$ keys would be about $5 \cdot 10^{61}$ ergs; the annual output of the Sun is about $1.21 \cdot 10^{41}$ ergs, so unless you can harness a considerably larger output than our Sun within 100 years, this is impossible
- A Grover's search (by a Quantum Computer) will also be impossible.  In theory, Grover's could find a 256 bit key in $O(2^{128})$ steps (which is far more achievable than the $2^{256}$ steps in the previous paragraph), it turns out that, to achieve this "low" amount of computation, Grover's search would require $O(2^{128})$ *sequential* AES evaluations (where you can't start the next until the previous one has completed).  If we assume that our Quantum Computer can't compute an AES function in less than a femtosecond ($10^{-15}$ seconds [1]), then this would take $10^{16}$ years, rather longer than your 100 year deadline.  To meet your deadline of 100 years, you would need to split up the key space into $2^{94}$ parts, and give each part to one of a total of $2^{94}$ Quantum Computers (each one performing AES operations at this completely unrealistic speed).
- Cryptographical advancement (that allows an attacker to recover the plaintext without trying all possible keys); this is an open question.  I personally don't expect a total break; that is, something that, given a reasonable amount of ciphertext (and possibly some known plaintext), will allow them to decrypt; I wouldn't be that shocked if someone in the next hundred years found a theoretical break (e.g. $O(2^{150})$ effort given vast mounds of chosen plaintext).  However, this is what people are worried about (as it is easy to see that the other two break methods are totally infeasible).

---

[1]: For reference, a femtosecond is approximately the time it takes light to travel 0.3 microns; this implies that our AES evaluation engine must be considerably smaller than your average bacteria...

Comment: To whoever downvoted me: why?  Is there something that I wrote which was incorrect?  That did not address the question?